# DialogFragment doesn't play exit animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a DialogFragment with a enter and exit animation.  Enter plays, exit does not.

I've tried both of these methods in `OnStart()`;

```
getDialog().getWindow()
                    .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;

getDialog().getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `style` in your `styles.xml`.

The first code to set the window animations should work. Post the transition animations here so that we can help you further.

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/enterAnim</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/exitAnim</item>
</style>
```